# You are here, but where's here?

Tags: feature-request, design

I find the `.youarehere a` styling for the main navigation links causes the text to be a little difficult to read on the also-blue header background. Could we give it a little bit of background colour or something else that would provide more contrast?

For example:

[image: contrasted youarehere link]

which is the product of the following CSS*:

```css
.nav ul li {
    margin: -2px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.nav ul li.youarehere {
    background-color: rgba(0, 80, 112, 0.25);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav ul li.youarehere a {
    color: #A1E9FF;
}
```

<sub>*For bonus points, also reduce the line height for the codeblocks!</sub>

Comment: +1 just for the title!

Comment: Whereever I go, there I am.

Comment: Looks like [this has now been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278101/questions-link-almost-unreadable-when-active-on-meta). I'd suggest closing this as a duplicate of the request that actually got implemented (even though it's newer).

Answer (score 6):

I've added something very similar to the CSS rules suggested above to the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.16.  The specific rules I ended up using are:

```css
.nav ul li.youarehere a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: -5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 80, 112, 0.25);
    color: #A1E9FF;
}
```

(The main advantage of re-styling only the `a` elements, besides letting me combine everything into a single CSS rule, is that it avoids having to mess with the existing padding and margin rules on the `li` elements.)

The re-styled navigation bar looks like this<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Screenshots of restyled meta.SE navigation bar]

<sup>1) Animation only for illustrative purposes.  Actual navigation bar will not be animated (except if you keep clicking the links to make it look like it is).</sup>