# Questions link almost unreadable when active on meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, meta

[image]

If you click on [Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) the font color is almost unreadable on the main site here.

Is it possible to make it a slightly different color? (I cannot say if darker *or* lighter is better)

Comment: The hover color of all the links looks to be the same (eyeballing it), it's just not bolded like the active link is.

Comment: Ok @Kendra then maybe all of them should be altered :-) the Questions link is on a different background so it is throwing me off a little.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to report this issue. I'm sorry the links don't have enough contrast to read. I've taken some time to update the design a bit to help make the current link more readable. Here is what the menu will now look like:

[image: New Meta.SE Header]

This fix will be made with the next production build.

Comment: I have it. I like it :c)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :-)

Comment: Presumably [this similar earlier feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229797/you-are-here-but-wheres-here) should also be marked as [meta-tag:status-completed] (or closed as a duplicate of this one).